# OpenSSL build on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, perl, openssl

The following error occurs when i try to build OpenSSL:

[image: Compile error]

***Error***:

```
link /nologo /subsystem:console /opt:ref /debug /out:out32\md4test.exe @C:\Users\DIEGO~1.J
ES\AppData\Local\Temp\nmFB55.tmp
libeay32.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __iob_func referenc
ed in function OPENSSL_showfatal
libeay32.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
libeay32.lib(pem_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
libeay32.lib(ui_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
out32\md4test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\am
d64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
```

Steps i followed (Windows 10 64 bits):

1. perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=c:\libs\openssl-1.0.1h\lib64
2. ms\do_win64a
3. nmake -f ms\nt.mak

Active Perl is installed.

From some search i made i discovered there's some compatibility problems with Visual Studio 2015 related to OpenSSL files.

Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Please don't add the errors as an image but use copy+paste. This way someone can find this post when looking for the same error.

Comment: *"From some search i made i discovered there's some compatibility problems with Visual Studio 2015 related to OpenSSL files..."* - I'm fairly certain OpenSSL 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 work as expected on Windows 10. I don't know about 1.0.1 since I no longer use it or test it.

Comment: The `lib64` in `-prefix=c:\libs\openssl-1.0.1h\lib64` looks unusual because your link commands appears to be missing `/machine:x64`. It looks like a 32-bit tools chain mixing with a 64-bit OpenSSL configuration. Did you open the x64 Developer Command Prompt? Or another one? Also, `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` is Visual Studio 2008 (IIRC), not Visual Studio 2015.